# Optimize Laravel Query for count base on type

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

[image]

In my dashboard, I made these queries on my database

[image]

If I just need the counts base on the `type`, can I just not make a query again?

I'm trying to optimize the page load. Please suggest how would one do this in the cheapest way possible.

```
public function index(){


    if(Request::get('code') == 'l!ght'){

        if(Request::get('date') == null) {

            $dateTime = new \DateTime();
            $date = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');

        } else {

            $date = Request::get('date'); 
            
        }

        $q = Norden::whereDate('updated_at', '=', $date);
        $nordens = $q->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();

        // dd($nordens);
        
        $feeds = Norden::where('type', 'feed')->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
        $latestFeed = $feeds->first();

        $countPoop = count(Norden::whereDate('updated_at', '=', $date)->where('type', 'poop')->get());
        $countPee  = count(Norden::whereDate('updated_at', '=', $date)->where('type', 'pee')->get());
        $countFeed = count(Norden::whereDate('updated_at', '=', $date)->where('type', 'feed')->get());


        $t        = strtotime($latestFeed->updated_at);
        $d        = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $t );
        $t        = $t + 2.5*(3600);
        $nextFeed = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $t );

        return View::make('layouts.be.norden.index', get_defined_vars());
    
    } else {

        return Redirect::to('/');

    }
}
```

Should I store the first query result into the array? and parse that array to get the count? Will that be better or worse in term of performance ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code:

```
public function index(){
    if(Request::get('code') == 'l!ght'){
        if(Request::get('date') == null) {
            $dateTime = new \DateTime();
            $date = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
        } else {
            $date = Request::get('date');
        }

        $q = Norden::whereDate('updated_at', '=', $date);
        $nordens = $q->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();

        // dd($nordens);

        $latestFeed = Norden::where('type', 'feed')->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->first();

        $nordenCountTypes = Norden::whereDate('updated_at', '=', $date)
            ->whereIn('type', ['feed', 'pee', 'poop'])
            ->selectRaw('type, count(type) as count')
            ->groupBy('type')
            ->get()
            ->keyBy('type');
        $countFeed = $nordenCountTypes['feed']['count'];
        $countPee = $nordenCountTypes['pee']['count'];
        $countPoop = $nordenCountTypes['pee']['poop'];

        $t        = strtotime($latestFeed->updated_at);
        $d        = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $t );
        $t        = $t + 2.5*(3600);
        $nextFeed = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $t );

        return View::make('layouts.be.norden.index', get_defined_vars());
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}
```

> Note: Be sure indexed  updated_at and type column in DB

> For count, you can use the count() method, which has much better performance

like this

```
        $countPoop = Norden::whereDate('updated_at', '=', $date)->where('type', 'poop')->count();
```

Comment: Why use `->groupBy('type')` & also `->keyBy('type');` ? Can you explain that in your answer ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if `->count();` is good ... why you didn't use it as part of the answer in the `index()`;`